# Jaggedy motion of text moving inside circle (PROCESSING)

Tags: processing

I have a circle with a text inside it. The circle is moving about, and the text is moving with it.

The circle moves smoothly, but the movement of the text is clearly jagged/laggy and in general unsmooth.

How can this be fixed?

```
    ellipse(position.x, position.y, radius*2, radius*2);
    fill(255);
    textSize(radius/3);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(mytext, position.x, position.y);
```

All variables here belong to the circle, such as its positions, radius, and the text inside of it.

The circle moves about since `position.x, position.y` changes slightly for every call, but the text movement is lagged.

I tried increasing FPS but that didn't solve the problem.

It works fine when the circle is moving straight up/down or left/right, but whenever it moves diagonally, the text movement becomes lagged. So I think that might be relevant in some way.

EDIT: For example, in this, the text inside the circle is laggy:

```
void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);


}

float x = 250, y = 250;


void draw()
{
  background(255);
  x += 0.1;
  y += 0.1;
  fill(120, 120, 120);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
  fill(0);
  text("hello", x, y);


}
```

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the code that I can see. Can you give me a (minimal) working example which I could run on my machine to see what you see?

Comment: Yes, I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you need to use floats as position, which for some reason the default renderer seems to dislike specifically regarding text, you can switch to another rendered.

Of course, this max tax your machine a little bit more. There's a cost to this kind of maneuver.

```
size(500, 500, P3D);
```

You'll notice that the move is significantly smoother, and appears slightly different. That's because processing will be using your graphic card to process some of the math involved in drawing your sketch. Theoretically, your sketch should run smoother and faster, but some people see their CPU usage goes up while doing this, or sometimes the sketch takes slightly more time to load. People with issues with P3D should be the minority, though.

Hope this helps. I think this issue is freaky.

Comment: In addition to this, increasing the framerate will also help hide the problem to a certain degree (as well as `textMode()` when possible). I am curious to what a clean solution would look like to get buttery smooth text animation in Processing.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem possible to overcome with the `text()` method at least.

What's seemingly happening in each renderer (except `P3D`) is that text is being drawn at integer intervals (no sub-pixel positioning), jumping between pixels every additional +=0.5 in either axis and this causes the jagged motion.

In `Java2D` mode for example (`PGraphicsJava2D`) text/character position is explicitly cast to an integer:

`g2.drawChars(buffer, start, length, (int) (x + 0.5f), (int) (y + 0.5f));`

I don't see the coordinates being cast to integers in the `FX2D` and `P2D` renderers so the rounding must lie with the renderer itself (glyphs are drawn/stamped individually as `PImage`s so perhaps that is why).

---

Perhaps the simplest workaround is to render the text as a PShape (vector graphic). To do this we first load a font (as a `PFont`) then use the `.charAt()` method to get a vector shape for each character. Characters can be arranged into a single PShape and finally drawn as a vector using the `shape()` method. Thankfully, `shape()` allows sub-pixel positioning so we avoid the jaggedness present in `text()`.

The `getVectorText()` method below does this for you.

#### Code

```
import processing.javafx.*;

PFont font;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, FX2D);
  font = createFont("Arial", 24);
  textFont(font);
}

float x = 250, y = 250;

void draw() {
  background(255);
  x += 0.1;
  y += 0.1;
  fill(120, 120, 120);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
  fill(0);
  text("hello", x, y);
  shape(getVectorText("hello"), x + 60, y);
}

PShape getVectorText(String text) {
  PShape textShape = createShape(GROUP);
  textShape.setStroke(false);

  float translationX = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    PShape character = font.getShape(c);

    character.translate(translationX, 0); // offset each character
    character.disableStyle(); // parent shape should override style
    textShape.addChild(character);

    translationX += font.width(c) * font.getSize(); // width() returns width with size 1, so scale up
  }

  return textShape;
}
```

#### Outcome

A comparison between the text drawn using `text()` (jagged) vs `shape()` (smooth).

[image]

Comment: Great answer (+1). Minor note for other Processing users: if the text isn't dynamic the text PShape group can cached (by calling `getVectorText()`) in `setup()` instead of continously in `draw()`) to improve performance a wee bit)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

Seems like processing isn't rounding both number the same way. You can manually round your numbers so this doesn't happens.

Here's the code snippet you can change to avoid the jagged movements manually. The important part is `floor()`, where I round the numbers myself to avoid letting processing deciding on my behalf:

```
void draw()
{
  background(255);
  x += 0.1;
  y += 0.1;
  fill(120, 120, 120);
  ellipse(floor(x), floor(y), 50, 50);
  fill(0);
  text("hello", floor(x), floor(y));
}
```

Have fun.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem because now the movement of the circle is jagged, since you are rounding its position each time, which prevents smoothness.